# Differences in showing disk usage percentage

Tags: linux, command-line, diskspace, arch

I'm using Arch Linux.

When I run `df -T` command it gives me this:

```
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3      ext4     930449240 750685092 132430124  86% /home
```

As it can be seen, the number on "Use%" column displays **86** while through `echo $(awk "BEGIN {printf \"%.3f\n\", 771793804 * 100 / 930449240}")` I get **82.95**.

What do you think is causing the difference in numbers and which one is the more reliable one?

Comment: not sure what you are calculating in awk, but use% is used * 100 / (used + available)

Comment: (used + available) seems much closer. I was using the number for 1K-blocks instead.